# how to return a GET method url in spring Framework using controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I created a small project for add users using spring framework...it is working very well fine...i want to know how to return all users as a list when save is complete...i already created a @REQUESTMAPING for get all users..It is working fine..I want to view it after save....thank u

user view controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/list" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(ModelMap model) {

        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "userslist";
    }
```

user save controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result,
            ModelMap model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

if(!userService.isUserSSOUnique(user.getId(), user.getSsoId())){
            FieldError ssoError =new FieldError("user","ssoId",messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.ssoId", new String[]{user.getSsoId()}, Locale.getDefault()));
            result.addError(ssoError);
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.saveUser(user);

        model.addAttribute("success", "User " + user.getFirstName() + " "+ user.getLastName() + " registered successfully");
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "userslist";
    }
```

when I save this t return userslist..but my datas are not view there because it is a just a JSP page....i want to view this by calling @request mapping...

Please help me someone

Comment: change return "userslist" with return "redirect:/list" to invoke listUsers() method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **redirect** to your `/list` after save the user like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result,
            ModelMap model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

if(!userService.isUserSSOUnique(user.getId(), user.getSsoId())){
            FieldError ssoError =new FieldError("user","ssoId",messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.ssoId", new String[]{user.getSsoId()}, Locale.getDefault()));
            result.addError(ssoError);
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.saveUser(user);

        model.addAttribute("success", "User " + user.getFirstName() + " "+ user.getLastName() + " registered successfully");
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "redirect:/list";
    }
```